Issue in store pickup delivery
I've created stock and sources and assigned my products successfully.
Now when I try to place an order using in-store delivery the following error message appear :
"qoute does not have pickup location assigned"
Could you please advise what I've to do ?
Thanks,

Go to Stores - Stocks in the backend and add a New Stock which assigns to the new source you made. Then you can edit your products to point to the new source and it will work!

That's what I did already
